# JSTL Google App Engine Problem

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

My problem is, that when the `<c:if` tag is reached the following problem occurs.

I am using Spring on google app engine.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
    at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.unExposeVariables(LoopTagSupport.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doFinally(LoopTagSupport.java:354)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.templates.master_005fb_jsp._jspx_meth_c_forEach_0(master_005fb_jsp.java:544)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.templates.master_005fb_jsp._jspx_meth_c_if_0(master_005fb_jsp.java:482)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.templates.master_005fb_jsp._jspService(master_005fb_jsp.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:94)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:324)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably a library version issues. Google AppEngine provides a default JSTL library and you don't have to include your own on the WEB-INF/lib directory. Just remove the library you might have added to that directory and clean build to test again.

Answer (score 2):

The `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` means that an abstract method as mentioned in the error message which is declared in some (abstract) API in the current runtime classpath is missing in the **concrete** implementation in the current runtime classpath.

In this case it's the `javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()` method. As per the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#getELContext%28%29) this abstract method was introduced in JSP 2.1. The concrete implementation is the **server** you're currently using.

This can be caused by having a `jsp-api.jar` of a *different* server make/version supporting JSP 2.1 in the runtime classpath of your webapp, most likely in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder, while the GAE server you're using doesn't implement JSP 2.1. Get rid of all server-specific libraries in the runtime classpath of your webapp. They doesn't belong there. They belongs (and are already) in the server's library.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an older version of JSTL. It looks like you're using 1.2 and you should probably be using 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

you don´t have to add any jstl library to web-inf/lib directory, just run